# How does http.createServer() know the parameters of the callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYcJQ.png)

http.createServer((req,res)=>{});

how the `createServer` function knows that the callback function has 'req' for incoming message object and 'res' for server response object automatically

Can someone show me an example of how to create a function like `createServer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is a class that contains 1 function called createServer, you can find some details on the HTTP object here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html, and when something like a request happens, the server returns your callback function with some parameters.

Hopefully, it will be easier to understand with 1 example:

You have the following class:

```
class User {
  userInfo = {
    name: "Jhon",
    surname: "Doe"
  }
  getFullName = (callback) => {
    return callback(this.userInfo.name, this.userInfo.surname)
  }
}
```

This class has 2 defined properties, userInfo that contains the name and surname of the "user", and 1 function, getFullName, that function expects another function as is input, and whenever we call it, we will receive 2 parameters as output:

```
const UserInfo = new User()
UserInfo.getFullName((name,surname) => console.log(`Hello ${name} ${surname}`))
```

Hopefully, that answers your question, if you have any further questions or I completely misunderstood your question, feel free to tell me!

Comment: Thank you so much but can you take a look at the picture I just add it to my question

Comment: The reason why the "createServer" callback knows that the first parameter is the request object a the second parameter is the response object its because somewhere on the node HTTP class (you can find it here https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8cf5ae07e9e80747c19e0fc04fad48423707f62c/lib/_http_server.js) there is some complex logic that at the end runs your callback like in my example, passing multiple parameters to your cb function on that specific order

Answer (score 6):

`http.createServer()` has no idea what you declared for callback parameters.  Regardless of how you declare your callback, `http.createServer()` passes two arguments to the callback when you call it.  The first is the http request object, the second is the http response object.  If your callback wants to work properly and use those arguments, it must create two arguments that match those.  You can name them anything you want.  The name is local only to your callback.

So, you can do any of these:

```
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.end("hi");
});

http.createServer((req, res, goop) => {
    // goop will be undefined here since no third argument is passed to the callback
    res.end("hi");
});

http.createServer((a, b) => {
    b.end("hi");
});

http.createServer((...args) => {
    args[1].end("hi");
});

http.createServer(function() {
    arguments[1].end("hi");
});
```

> Can someone show me an example of how to create a function like createServer

You can create a function that accepts a callback function and then you call that callback with a set of arguments:

```
function readJSON(filename, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            try {
                let json = JSON.parse(data);
                callback(null, json);
            } catch(e) {
                callback(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here you create a function that takes a filename and a callback.  It then reads that file, parses the JSON in it and calls the callback with `null` for the err and the parsed Javascript object for the 2nd parameter.  If there's an error, then it just passes the error as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you that's amazing, can you take a look at the picture I just add it to the question body

Comment: how can I create a function that passes two arguments to the callback when it gets called

Comment: @Moe - My answer already contains an example of a function you can create that accepts a callback as an argument and then calls that callback with one or two arguments depending upon the conditions.  I don't know what else you want from this answer and am surprised if you think this is amazing that you selected the other answer.  Did I not understand something you were asking?

Comment: @Moe - Your screenshot appears to be from an editor.  The editor would be getting typing information either from the documentation or inferred from usage or from TypeScript bindings.  Javascript, by itself, is not a typed language so a callback parameter is not declared with specific parameters.  To the language, it's just a callback function.  What it is called with is up to the caller and the recipient of that function call needs to just know what the arguments will be when its called.  If you want a typed version of Javascript, you can use TypeScript where these things have to be declared.